# Access Azure web app through reverse proxy

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, reverse-proxy

Can you tell me whether the following scenario could be possible?

I want to access an Azure web app through a reverse proxy running on-premise.
The proxy will be responsible to authenticate the users, add a JWT (or SAML) to the request and forward it to my Azure Web App.
The Azure Web App will authorize (or not) the user to perform the request.
Potentially, there can be multiple reverse proxies on different sites.

Anybody has experience with such a setup?
Of course, this prevent the Web App to be globally available but that is not an issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

An Azure Web App always has a public name and IP, therefor it is possible to bypass your reverse proxy and access directly the app using its public name, or IP.

However, if you need to make the traffic between your reverse proxy and the app private, you got a few options. You can either run your app in a VM or in an [App Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro). Both offer private network access, i.e. can be added to a virtual network and a VPN tunnel be built to your on-premises network.

Difference between an ASE and a VM is that the VM you manage and maintain, while the ASE is a private PaaS service, i.e. private app service managed and maintained by Microsoft, thus more limited in capabilities than a VM.

Pricewise, a normal Azure Web App is the cheapest option. VM or an ASE are considerably more expensive.

Comment: If the Azure Wep App is access directly, the token will not be there, so access will not be granted. Actually, the goal is more to avoid to sync all on-premise AD with AD connect.

Comment: You can limit which users or groups can access the app in Azure AD in the Azure portal, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-coreapps-assign-user-azure-portal. Not knowing your requirements, but you can also filter what Azure AD Connect syncs to the cloud, you can create filters for it when running the setup wizard. You can filter what to sync based on e.g. OU.